# How to Prove Homotopy Equivalence in a Discrete Topology

Tags: continuity, homotopy-theory, homotopy-type-theory

In order to understand what exactly is meant by *path* in homotopy type theory, I am looking into homotopies. This led to the following questions (some definitions follow):

1. **Intuition for how "continuous" works in a discrete system.** If a continuous function in a discrete graph/topology is really just moving along an edge at each step. Homotopy relies on the definition of continuity, so I'm wondering what it means in the discrete case. Just want to make sure I'm understanding the wikipedia quote (below).
2. **How to show/prove two functions (on a discrete topology) are homotopic**. Say I have two functions $x$ and $y$. They take 1 parameter. <del>Computationally (not sure if this matters) $x$ takes 3 computations to return its output, and $y$ takes 5.</del> They both create different output that is isomorphic to each other. $x(a) = p$ and $y(a) = q$, where $p$ and $q$ are isomorphic. How to show/prove they are homotopic (if at all). If they're not homotopic, what is an example of homotopy (in a discrete topology), and how to show they are homotopic.

---

These definitions are from Wikipedia, I can mostly follow them.

A [**continuous function**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Continuous_functions_between_topological_spaces) is:

- A function $f : X \to Y$ (between two topological spaces $X$ and $Y$)
- For every open set $V \subseteq Y$, the inverse image is an open subset of X.
  $$f^{-1}(V)=\{x\in X\;|\;f(x)\in V\}$$

> An extreme example: if a set $X$ is given the discrete topology (in which every subset is open), all functions $f\colon X\rightarrow T$ to any topological space $T$ are continuous.

A [**homotopy**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy#Formal_definition) is:

- Defined as two *continuous functions* $f$ and $g$
- From topological space $X$ to $Y$
- That can be *continuously* deformed into one another
- Formally, $H : X \times [0,1] \to Y$
- Such that: $x \in X \Rightarrow H(x,0) = f(x) \land H(x,1) = g(x)$

> We can also think of the second parameter as a "slider control" that allows us to smoothly transition from f to g as the slider moves from 0 to 1, and vice versa.

Comment: I think your questions are heading in the wrong direction if you are trying to understand HoTT. You should focus on points and paths in topological spaces, and you should picture them like manifolds for the most part. Graphs are not very common topological spaces in HoTT, although you can set them up. "Computation" doesn't come into it at all, and certainly not the way you are envisioning. (You don't usually count computation steps.)

Comment: Well a continuous map between spaces with the discrete topology is just a function, since the preimage is always open. A path in a discrete space is just a point. Generally, however, a path in a topological space $X$ is a continuous function $[0,1] \to X$. In $\mathbb{R}^2$, for example, one may visualize this as exactly that, a path going from one point to another.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro still would like to know how to show/prove two functions are homotopic. I removed the computation part. Nice, yeah I'm picturing them as manifolds like you suggest, but in terms of _proving_ two paths are equal, there's still the notion of steps in the proof. In that sense the proof topology is discrete, so I try to imagine the type manifold as discrete (it makes more sense to me than continuous).

Comment: @LancePollard The details of proving two functions are homotopic depends intimately on the particular topology. For example, if $Y=\Bbb R^2$ then any two paths are homotopic, because you can map $H(x,t)=(1-t)f(x)+tg(x)$. On the circle $X=Y=S_1$, a constant map and the identity map are not homotopic, because of the existence of the winding number, which is a continuous map from continuous functions $S_1\to S_1$ to integers.

Comment: Univalence gives a very strange topology to a universe, construed as a topological space. It is incredibly complicated, since it necessarily contains subspaces isomorphic to all homotopy spaces in the universe, but the univalence axiom says that there is a path between all points that represent isomorphic topological spaces.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro A univalent universe does not contain subspaces isomorphic to all spaces in the universe; each space is a *point* in the universe but the topology *of* that space is reflected in the universe only insofar as it determines the spaces of homotopy equivalences between that space and other spaces (including itself).